# Copying over drop downs

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA macro that copies over formulas and values from one sheet to another one. The problem is that when it copies over dropdown lists, it deletes the list and just copies over the value.

I tried both of the below, but both have the same problem

```
wb_to.Sheets("Core").Range(cel_loc_new).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValidation, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

and

```
wb_to.Sheets("Core").Range(cel_loc_new).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try specifying the destination in the `Copy` method. Something like `Range("A3").Copy Range("A4")` This should move the copied drop down to the destination range.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thank you. I do exactly that. I specify copy. However, when I paste it pastes the value instead of the drop down. The drop down disappears Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Can you provide some more information? What type of drop down is it? Data Validation Drop down? Active X? Something else?

Comment: Hi Ryan, sorry - it is a data validation list (drop down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is instead of using .Copy one has to do = .Value. So instead of copy and pasting you have to adjust the value of the cell.